# Integrate iContact API into my webpage's code

Tags: php, api

I now a have an icontact api.I have a register form on my web page and there is the checkbox "I want to receive the newsletter."I want the contacts who check this box to be saved in my icontact subscribers list.(Their e-mail should be saved)

The code for this that i have is this:

```
Download: icontact.api.functions.php
<?php
$iContactLists[1] = array('id' => '<list-id-number>', 'txt' => 'Weekly Newsletter');
$iContactLists[2] = array('id' => '<list-id-number>', 'txt' => 'Products Promotions and    Specials');
$iContactLists[3] = array('id' => '<list-id-number>', 'txt' => 'Event Notifications');

########################################################################
## Example call for the function below...                             ##
#                                                                     ##
#  addiContact($email, $fname, $lname, $iContactLists[$signup_key]);  ##
########################################################################
function addiContact($email, $fname, $lname, $list) {
$listId = $list['id'] ? $list['id'] : 0;
$listName = $list['txt'] ? $list['txt'] : 'UNKNOWN';
$retVal = 0;
$result = getContact($email, $list);
if($contactId = $result['id']) {
  $retVal = 1;
  $retMsg = "<p>Thank you for subscribing to the {$listName} mailing list!</p>\r\n";
} else {
  $result = getContact($email);
  $result = !$result['id'] ? addContact($email, $fname, $lname) : $result;
  $contactId = $result['id'];
  if(0 < $contactId) $result = subscribeContactToList($contactId, $list);
  $retVal = $result['val'];
  $retMsg = $result['msg'];
}
return array('val' => $retVal, 'msg' => $retMsg, 'id' => $contactId);
}




##################################################################################
##  There should not be any need to make direct calls to functions below here.  ##
##################################################################################
##################################################################################

define('STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS', 200);
$iContactAPIVars = array(
'apiUrl'   => 'https://app.icontact.com/icp',
'appUser'  => '<appUser>', 'appPass'  => '<appPass>',
'appId'    => '<appId>',
'accId'    => '<accId>', 'cliId'    => '<cliId>'
);

function WebCodeError($error_code) {
$retMsg = "Error Code: `{$error_code}` - ";
switch($error_code) {
  case 0:
  case "": $retMsg.= "Connection to API Unavailable"; break;
  case 200: $retMsg.= "OK"; break;
  case 400: $retMsg.= "Bad Request"; break;
  case 401: $retMsg.= "Not Authorized"; break;
  case 402: $retMsg.= "Payment Required"; break;
  case 403: $retMsg.= "Forbidden"; break;
  case 404: $retMsg.= "Not Found"; break;
  case 405: $retMsg.= "Method Not Allowed"; break;
  case 406: $retMsg.= "Not Acceptable"; break;
  case 415: $retMsg.= "Unsupported Media Type"; break;
  case 500: $retMsg.= "Internal Server Error"; break;
  case 501: $retMsg.= "Not Implemented"; break;
  case 503: $retMsg.= "Service Unavailable"; break;
  case 507: $retMsg.= "Insufficient Space"; break;
  default: $retMsg.= "UNHANDLED ERROR"; break;
}
return $retMsg;
}

function callResource($url, $method, $data = null) {
global $iContactAPIVars;
$url    = $iContactAPIVars['apiUrl'] . $url;
$handle = curl_init();
$headers = array(
  'Accept: application/json',
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'API-Version: 2.0',
  'API-AppId: ' . $iContactAPIVars['appId'],
  'API-Username: ' . $iContactAPIVars['appUser'],
  'API-Password: ' . $iContactAPIVars['appPass'],
);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
switch($method) {
  case 'POST':
      curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    break;
  case 'PUT':
      curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
      $file_handle = @fopen($data, 'r');
      curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file_handle);
    break;
  case 'DELETE':
      curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    break;
  default: break;
}
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($handle);
return array('code' => $code, 'data' => $response);
}

function getContact($email, $list = false) {
global $iContactAPIVars;
$listId = $list['id'] ? $list['id'] : 0;
$listName = $list['txt'] ? $list['txt'] : 'UNKNOWN';
$contactId = 0;
$retStatus = "no_status_loaded";
if(!$email)
  return array('id' => $contactId, 'msg' => "Invalid parameter values!<br/>\r\n", 'status' => $retStatus);
$callURI = "/a/{$iContactAPIVars['accId']}/c/{$iContactAPIVars['cliId']}/contacts?   email=".$email;
$callURI.= $listId ? "&listId=".$listId : "";
$response = callResource($callURI, 'GET');
if($response['code'] == STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS) {
  $contact = $response['data']['contacts'][0];
  if($contact['contactId']) {
    $contactId = $contact['contactId'];
    $retStatus = $contact['status'];
    $retMsg = "Successfully found contact!<br/>\r\n";
  } else {
    $retMsg = "Contact '{$email}' not found".($listId ? "in the {$listName} mailing list" : "").".<br/>\r\n";
  }
} else {
  $retMsg = "<p>A problem was encountered while looking to see if you already are subscribed to the {$listName} mailing list.</p>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "<p>".WebCodeError($response['code'])."</p>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "<p>Call URI: {$callURI}</p>\r\n";
}
return array('id' => $contactId, 'msg' => $retMsg, 'status' => $retStatus);
}

function addContact($email, $fname, $lname) {
global $iContactAPIVars;
$contactId = 0;
if(!$email || !$fname || !$lname) return array('id' => $contactId, 'msg' => "Invalid parameter values!<br/>\r\n");
$callURI = "/a/{$iContactAPIVars['accId']}/c/{$iContactAPIVars['cliId']}/contacts";
$callValues = array( 'email' => $email, 'firstName' => $fname, 'lastName'  => $lname, 'status' => 'normal' );
$response = callResource($callURI, 'POST', array($callValues));
if($response['code'] == STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS) {
  $contactId = $response['data']['contacts'][0]['contactId'];
  $retMsg = "<p>Contact added!</p>\r\n";
} else {
  $retMsg = "<p>A problem was encountered while adding your e-mail information.</p>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "<p>".WebCodeError($response['code'])."</p>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "<p>Call URI: {$callURI}</p>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "<p>Call Values:<br/>\r\n";
  foreach($callValues as $key => $val) $retMsg.= "  [{$key}] => {$val}<br/>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "</p>\r\n";
}
return array('id' => $contactId, 'msg' => $retMsg);
}

function subscribeContactToList($contactId, $list) {
global $iContactAPIVars;
$listId = $list['id'] ? $list['id'] : 0;
$listName = $list['txt'] ? $list['txt'] : 'UNKNOWN';
$retVal = 0;
if(!$contactId || !$listId) return array('val' => $retVal, 'msg' => "Invalid parameter values!<br/>\r\n");
$callURI = "/a/{$iContactAPIVars['accId']}/c/{$iContactAPIVars['cliId']}/subscriptions";
$callValues = array( 'contactId' => $contactId, 'listId' => $listId, 'status' => 'normal' );
$response = callResource($callURI, 'POST', array($callValues));
if($response['code'] == STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS) {
  $retVal = 1;
  $retMsg = "<p>Thank you for subscribing to the {$listName} mailing list!</p>\r\n";
} else {
  $retMsg = "<p>A problem was encountered while adding you to the {$listName} mailing list.</p>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "<p>".WebCodeError($response['code'])."</p>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "<p>Call URI: {$callURI}</p>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "<p>Call Values:<br/>\r\n";
  foreach($callValues as $key => $val) $retMsg.= "  [{$key}] => {$val}<br/>\r\n";
  $retMsg.= "</p>\r\n";
}
return array('val' => $retVal, 'msg' => $retMsg);
}


?>;
```

When I use this it doesnt work at all.I changed the variables,but still...

Comment: Define "doesn't work at all". C'mon. Errors? Blank page? What do your server logs say?

Comment: It returns only a blank page :(

Answer (score 1):

When I loaded up your code, I didn't get a blank page. I got a ";", because that's what's left after the final closing php tag.

Perhaps the problem is the code you have only defines functions, and never calls them.

I'm guessing you want to have something more like this at the end of your code:

```
# Assume if there is POST data we should process the signup
if (count($_POST)) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $list = $_POST['list'];
    $results = addiContact($email, $fname, $lname, $list);
    print_r($results);  # You should do something more useful here
}

## Generate and display the form
$selectBox = '<select name="list">';
foreach($iContactLists as $list) {
    $selectBox .= "<option value=\"{$list['id']}\">{$list['txt']}</option>\n";
}
$selectBox .= '</select>';
?>
<form method="POST">
Email: <input name="email"/><br />
First name: <input name="fname"/><br />
Last name: <input name="lname"/><br />
List: <?= $selectBox ?><br />
<input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below sample code in PHP will help you to delete the contact from the particular iContact List.

PHP Code:

```
$headers = array(
    'Accept: text/xml',
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'Api-Version: 2.0',
    'Api-AppId: ' . $app_id,
    'Api-Username: ' . $user,
    'Api-Password: ' . $pass
);

$ch=curl_init("https://app.sandbox.icontact.com/icp/a/$account_id/c/$folder_id/contacts/{contactId}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$deleteResult   = curl_exec($ch);
$deleteParse    = simplexml_load_string($deleteResult);
print "<pre>";
print_r($deleteParse);
print "<pre>";
curl_close($ch);
```